# how to resolve "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I am getting following error in Python:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error while trying to run a webdriver
```

I have attached my code here

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.chrome(r"C:\Users\nkumaresan\Desktop\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.javatpoint.com/selenium-basic-terminology")
driver.close()
```

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example of your code. Now it is even not clear in which language your program is written.